# Breaking Out JSON Result Into Localstorage Key/Value Pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I have a valid JSON result:

```
{
"metadata": [
    {
        "name": "md1",
        "value": "blah1"
    },
    {
        "name": "md2",
        "value": "blah2"
    },
    {
        "name": "tee2",
        "value": "blah3"
    }
],
"subdata1": [
    {
        "name": "sd1_1",
        "value": "blah1_1"
    },
    {
        "name": "sd1_2",
        "value": "blah1_2"
    },
    {
        "name": "sd1_3",
        "value": "blah1_3"
    },
    {
        "name": "sd1_4",
        "value": "blah1_1"
    }
],
"subdata2": [
    {
        "name": "sd2_1",
        "value": "blah2_1"
    },
    {
        "name": "sd2_2",
        "value": "blah2_2"
    },
    {
        "name": "sd2_3",
        "value": "blah2_3"
    }
]
```

}

coming in via a successful jQuery .ajax() call:

```
$.ajax({
           url: 'test.json',
           type: 'get',
           datatype: 'json',
           processData: false,
           success: function(data) { //do something...};
```

It's relatively easy to blob the entire result into a value associated with an overall key:

```
localStorage.setItem('newtest', data);
```

This would save the entirety of my JSON response as a value with a key called "newtest". But suppose I want each array's descriptor as the key name and the associated array as the value? In my example, that would give me three key/value pairs, with each array saved as a separate string value associated with keys named "metadata," "subdata1" and "subdata2", respectively. I've done a great deal of searching but have not come across the correct approach for this. Any help towards a solution would be greatly appreciated -- thank you for your attention and assistance.

Comment: I thought localstorage values had to be simple strings. You'd need to serialize the arrays before storing them.

Comment: If you want to use complex objects without serialisation you should look into [IndexedDb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/IndexedDB), but AFAIK the API is still quite young.

Comment: @Blazemonger, I'm no expert here, but if I simply add: "localStorage.setItem('newtest', data);", I get my complete JSON result saved without error into localstorage. If I try something like: "var newdata = $(data).serializeArray();" and then  "localStorage.setItem('newtest', newdata);", I get endless "/n" linebreaks in ls. The first scenario is preferable, since I then have the complete string available for manipulation without extra characters. FWIW, I _am_ serializing/setItem/stringify-ing form data from HTML into localstorage onclick, but I need to set localstorage on load via AJAX first.

Comment: Also: 'localStorage.setItem("newtest", data);' seems to leave a string in valid JSON format, whereas actually stringifying it as part of setItem, e.g. 'localStorage.setItem("newtest", JSON.stringify(data))' adds forward slashes and otherwise invalid JSON, even when I remove the linebreaks from the actual JSON accesses via $.ajax(). For all my research and attempts to try different approaches, this is proving very challenging for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a for loop and stringify the objects.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.json',
    type: 'get',
    datatype: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        for(var key in data){
            localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data[key]));
        }
    }
});
```

Then parse when you get them

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("metadata"));
```

Comment: That's giving me a pretty screwy, system-freezing result that appears to be breaking down every last character in the JSON to an individual numeral in local storage, e.g.: key => value pairs like 0 => "{", 1 => "\n", 10 => "a", 100 => " ", 1000 => "d", etc. Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe take your results and run it through an online json linter to make sure the json is valid.  I tested the code above with your example json and it worked.

Comment: I'm at JSONLint.com many times a day trying to ensure my JSON responses are valid. I have created a dummy page with only your Javascript above and the same JSON I posted up top -- here's a screenshot of the same result I described in my first reply to you: ![Screenshot](http://www.metaharmonic.com/images/localstorage.png). I wish I understood why it works for you but not me.

Comment: I think it's because you're running it as a file rather than on a server.  Chrome can act funny with things like cookies and local storage when you run it as a file.  Check the local storage after running the code on this http://jsfiddle.net/94jjQ/

Comment: That's it, sir, thanks. I wondered if it could be a browser issue but I get similar freezing results in Safari, albeit with different numeric patterns for keys -- I'd also greatly welcome any insight as to why you get such strange (and at least in those numeric patterns, slightly different) results locally as opposed to from a server where HTML and JSON share the same domain. I am, after all, still using a JSON "file" out there, too.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on how it all works, but I've found some threads talking about it.  This one explains why it's hard to have cookies work on local files - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/iow88FsnNhQ/WoFikAKUTZ8J

This one explains how to enable file cookies - http://wolfslittlestore.be/2012/08/cookies-on-local-files-in-chrome/

There were some other stackoverflow threads going on about the cookie stuff, I would assume local storage falls in a similar scenario.  How to map the saved data to a file on a large file system with the possibility that the user can move the file.